# Creating a symlink on Windows during JVM runtime

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, cmd

Slightly bizarre set of questions but I'm running into issues creating a symlink using `mklink` on Windows 7. I'm doing something a little weird due to the 260 character limit that exists when using `cmd.exe` by creating symlinks inside of my Java source code by using `Process`. Since I can't quite explain it, here's the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class WindowsSymlinkUtility {

    private List<String> command, currentSymlinks;

    public WindowsSymlinkUtility() {
        this.command = this.currentSymlinks = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.command.add("cmd.exe");
        this.command.add("/C");
    }

    /**
     * Automatically creates a directory junction
     * @param String link - the path and name of the symlink
     * @param String target - the directory to point the symlink to
     * @return boolean
     * @see http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html
     */
    public boolean createSymlink(String link, String target) {
        return createSymlink("\\J", link, target);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param String flag - the flag for mklink
     * @param String link - the path and name of the symlink
     * @param String target - the directory to point the symlink to
     * @return boolean
     * @see http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html
     */
    public boolean createSymlink(String flag, String link, String target) {
        this.command.clear();
        this.command.add("mklink");
        this.command.add(flag);
        this.command.add(link);
        this.command.add(target);
        this.currentSymlinks.add(link);

        return this.runner() == 0;
    }

    public boolean removeSymlink(String link) {
        this.command.clear();
        this.command.add("RD");
        this.command.add(link);

        if(this.runner() != 0) {
            this.command.clear();
            this.command.add("DEL");
            this.command.add(link);
        } else {
            return true;
        }

        return this.runner() == 0;
    }

    public boolean removeAllSymlinks() {
        for(String link : this.currentSymlinks) {
            if(!this.removeSymlink(link)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Leave for debugging purposes
     * @return String
     */
    public String getCurrentCommand() {
        String cmd = "";
        for(String part : this.command) {
            cmd += part + " ";
        }

        return cmd;
    }

    private int runner() {
        Process process = null;
        String message = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        int exitVal = -1;
        StringBuilder strBuff = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            if(this.command.size() < 1) throw new Exception("Length of Windows command cannot be zero");

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(this.command);
            Map<String, String> envVars = pb.environment();

            pb.directory();
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            process = pb.start();
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(process.getInputStream());
            byte[] bArr = new byte[2048];
            while (bis.read(bArr) != -1) {
                strBuff.append(new String(bArr).trim());
                bArr = new byte[2048];
            }

            exitVal = process.waitFor();
            message = strBuff.toString();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.err.println(message);
        }

        return exitVal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WindowsSymlinkUtility foo = new WindowsSymlinkUtility();
        foo.createSymlink("%TEMP%\\foo", "C:\\Users\\djthomps\\Downloads");
    }

}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mklink": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at WindowsSymlinkUtility.runner(WindowsSymlinkUtility.java:113)
        at WindowsSymlinkUtility.createSymlink(WindowsSymlinkUtility.java:56)
        at WindowsSymlinkUtility.createSymlink(WindowsSymlinkUtility.java:37)
        at WindowsSymlinkUtility.main(WindowsSymlinkUtility.java:134)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 5 more
Cannot run program "mklink": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
null
```

Some questions you might have:

1. Why are you doing this?

   - Because the length of the full command runs well over 260 characters due to relevant files and folders being deeply nested in the file system.
2. How will symlinks help?

   - I have done tests to ensure that symlinks allow me to "bypass" the 260 character limit.

Here are my questions:

1. Is there another way to create a symlink in Java such that Windows will behave when a command *exceeds* the 260 character limit?
2. Can `SET` be used in lieu of `mklink`?
3. Is it possible to use `java.nio.file` for this even if the command runs over 260 characters?

Again, I understand this is an odd question. Ask for clarification if something is amiss.

Comment: You need to use the `full path` to the mklink program or set an environmental variable... ie. `c:\windows\system32\mklink` java doesn't add windows paths by default.

Comment: @EddieB: what environment variable?  I thought Java just used PATH, like everything else?

Comment: The problem is a typo in the createSymlink(link, target) function - a backslash instead of a forward slash where you specify /J as the flag.

Comment: @HarryJohnston The Java `application` uses path. If you want to run a system process `this application` needs the full path to it. Also, you are correct about the OP's incorrect flag.. but that's another issue :)

Comment: @EddieB: actually looking at it again I think the underlying problem is that mklink is an internal command, i.e., there isn't an executable.  The OP needs to put `cmd /c` at the beginning of the command line.

Comment: Another problem: `this.command` and `this.currentSymlinks` are initialized to point to the same string array, which is clearly not what is intended.

Comment: You do know about the [Files.createSymbolicLink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createSymbolicLink-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) method, right?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes... I was taking a look at it... Apparently [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) does have access to the env vars ... so after taking a look at the error it's apparent that he's not properly concatenating the string. He needs to concat the arguments into one as `mklink` is an internal script for `cmd`.

Comment: @VGR: based on the code, and since creating symbolic links requires administrator privilege, I believe the OP actually wants to create a junction point.

Comment: @EddieB: yeah, there's a `cmd /c` added during initialization, but it's deleted again at the start of createSymlink(flag, link, target).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eddie B's solution was on the right track but I kept getting errors when Java as attempting to run the command. Here's my rendition that works:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class WindowsSymlinkUtility {

    public static final String D_LINK = "/D";
    public static final String H_LINK = "/H";
    public static final String J_LINK = "/J";
    public static final String REM_LINK = "rmdir";

    private String command, flag, link, target;
    private List<String> commands = Arrays.asList(D_LINK, H_LINK, J_LINK, REM_LINK), symlinks;

    public WindowsSymlinkUtility() {
        this.command = this.flag = this.link = this.target = "";
        this.symlinks = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Automatically creates a directory junction
     * @param String link - the path and name of the symlink
     * @param String target - the directory to point the symlink to
     * @return boolean
     * @see http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html
     */
    public boolean createSymlink(String link, String target) {
        return createSymlink(J_LINK, link, target);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param String flag - the flag for mklink
     * @param String link - the path and name of the symlink
     * @param String target - the directory to point the symlink to
     * @return boolean
     * @see http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html
     */
    public boolean createSymlink(String flag, String link, String target) {
        if(!this.commands.contains(flag)) {
            System.err.printf("%s is not a valid command\n", flag);
            return false;
        }

        this.command = "mklink";
        this.flag = flag;
        this.link = link;
        this.target = target;

        if(this.runner() == 0) {
            this.symlinks.add(this.link);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private int runner() {
        Process process = null;
        String message = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        StringBuilder strBuff = new StringBuilder();
        int exitVal = -1;

        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", this.command, this.flag, this.link, this.target);
            Map<String, String> envVars = pb.environment();

            pb.directory();
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            process = pb.start();
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(process.getInputStream());
            byte[] bArr = new byte[2048];
            while (bis.read(bArr) != -1) {
                strBuff.append(new String(bArr).trim());
                bArr = new byte[2048];
            }

            exitVal = process.waitFor();
            message = strBuff.toString();
            System.out.println(message);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.err.println(message);
        }

        return exitVal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new WindowsSymlinkUtility()).createSymlink(J_LINK, "%TEMP%\\node", "C:\\users\\djthomps\\Downloads");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've modified your program a bit just to provide a working sample... essentially the problem is that you're not concatenating the variables and passing them as one argument to `cmd`.

One implementation note :: **Do Not** use `del` to remove a symlink otherwise all the files in the target directory will be erased. Use `rmdir`, which I've added for posterity.

```
/**
 * @author Edward Beckett :: <Edward@EdwardBeckett.com>
 * @since :: 7/21/2015
 */
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class WindowsSymlinkUtility {

    public static final String D_LINK = "/D";
    public static final String H_LINK = "/H";
    public static final String J_LINK = "/J";
    public static final String REM_LINK = "rmdir";
    private String command = "";
    private String link = "";
    private String target = "";

    private List<String> commands = Arrays.asList( D_LINK, H_LINK, J_LINK, REM_LINK );

    public void createSymlink( String command, String link, String target ) {
        this.command = command;
        this.link = link;
        this.target = target;

        if( !commands.contains( command ) ) {
            System.out.println( command + " Is not a valid command \n " );
            return;
        }
        runner();
    }


    private void runner() {

        try {

            String[] values = { "CMD", "/C", "mklink", this.command, this.link, this.target };
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder( values );
            builder.directory( new File( this.link ) );
            Process process = builder.start();
            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader( is );
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( isr );
            String line;
            System.out.printf( "Output of running %s is:\n",
                Arrays.toString( values ) );
            while( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ) {
                System.out.println( line );
                int exitValue = process.waitFor();
                System.out.println( "\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue );
            }
        } catch( InterruptedException | IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        public static void main( String[] args ) {
        ( new WindowsSymlinkUtility() ).createSymlink( J_LINK, "C:\\Foo", "C:\\Temp" );
    }

}
```

> output

```
Output of running [CMD, /C, mklink, /J, C:\Foo, C:\Temp] is:
Junction created for C:\Foo <<===>> C:\Temp
Exit Value is 0
```

Comment: Huh, so I tried this a few different ways: 1. `(new WindowsSymlinkUtility()).createSymlink(J_LINK, "C:\\temp", "C:\\Users\\djthomps\\Downloads\\");` 2. `(new WindowsSymlinkUtility()).createSymlink(J_LINK, "C:\\temp\\node", "C:\\Users\\djthomps\\Downloads\\");` and I'm not getting any output saying the symlink was actually created. In this exact use case I'd just want to create a symlink between the directory where `node.exe`. Here is the error for the first use: `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "CMD" (in directory "C:\temp\node"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid`

Comment: Ran out of room. The second one produces nothing after `Output of running [CMD, /C, mklink, /J, C:\temp, C:\Users\djthomps\Downloads\] is` Edit: `mklink /J C:\temp\node C:\Users\djthomps\Downloads` running this command works

Comment: Your problem was adding the trailing directory slash(s).